# Count rows from an SQL statement and store in PHP variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following SQL code in my PHP file. I want to count the number of rows returned and store it in a variable so I can output it on the page.

I've tried a few solutions I found but none of them worked.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, owner_id, hs_name, hs_address FROM hotspots WHERE owner_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($hsid, $ownerid, $hsname, $hsaddress);

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    // print results in loop
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ha, that is coincidental! Unfortunately, I couldn't get that to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding

```
$stmt->store_result();
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
```

After the execute, so the entire thing now looks like

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, owner_id, hs_name, hs_address FROM hotspots WHERE owner_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->bind_result($hsid, $ownerid, $hsname, $hsaddress);
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQLi provides a nice way of doing this, you can simply use the [`num_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) property on the statement after it has been executed. This will immediately return the number of rows returned by the statement.

```php
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
```

Comment: I had actually already tried that - it returns 0 for some reason. The actual return for my demo should be 2. It is definitely returning 2 results as I can print them.

Comment: @JamesGrunshaw Which SQL engine are you using? MySQL, SQLite,... ?